# Converting PDFs to Images using Poppler. It works for one file, but not when looping through a folder of PDFs?

Tags: anaconda, python-3.6, pdf-conversion, poppler

I'm working to convert a folder of PDFs to JPG images. I'm using Poppler and when I have it working at one image at a time it works. However, when looping through each PDF file within a folder it gives the following error:
"PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?"
Since I know Poppler is installed and in PATH (and working for a single sample) I'm wondering if my looping is somehow causing the issue?
For context, please note this is being down in Windows on Spyder in Anaconda; python-3.6.

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path 
import os

for filename in os.listdir(r".\I. Original Data\PDF Files"):
    if filename.endswith(r".pdf"):
        with open(os.path.join(r".\I. Original Data\PDF Files", filename)) as f:
            pages = convert_from_path(f, 1000)
            image_counter = 1
            for page in pages:
                filename = ".\II. Transformation\page_" + str(image_counter) + ".jpg"
                page.save(filename, 'JPEG')
                image_counter = image_counter + 1
```

I'm hoping to have a final product that can output each page of each PDF into a separate file within the referenced 'Transformation' folder.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for filename in os.listdir(r".\I. Original Data\PDF Files"):    
    filepath = (".\I. Original Data\PDF Files\\" + filename)
    pages = convert_from_path(filepath, 1000)
    image_counter = 1
    for page in pages:
        file = ".\II. Transformation\\" + str(os.path.splitext(filename)[0]) + "_page_" + str(image_counter) + ".jpg"
        page.save(file, 'JPEG')
        image_counter = image_counter + 1
```